# Magento ver. 1.3.1 with MySQL 5.6.35 and PHP 5.6.30. Could it work?

Tags: system-configuration

```
Magento ver. 1.3.1
Apache Version  2.4.25
PHP Version 5.6.30
MySQL Version   5.6.35 or possibly php55
```

I had a website running on an old server (with lower pHp and mySQL versions) but I needed to discontinue that server and so I migrated everything to a new server which has the specifications listed above. Now it gives me the Error below:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 145 Table './mySTORE_shop/log_visitor' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
Trace:  
#0 /home/mySTORE/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(283): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/mySTORE/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(457): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 /home/mySTORE/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(230): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#3 /home/mySTORE/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(259): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#4 /home/mySTORE/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(535): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#5 /home/mySTORE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(349): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_visitor', Array)
#6 /home/mySTORE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(251): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#7 /home/mySTORE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(157): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#8 /home/mySTORE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1167): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#9 /home/mySTORE/public_html/app/Mage.php(301): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#10 /home/mySTORE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(410): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#11 /home/mySTORE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(45): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#12 /home/mySTORE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(356): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#13 /home/mySTORE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(247): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#14 /home/mySTORE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(158): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /home/mySTORE/public_html/app/Mage.php(457): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /home/garden/public_html/index.php(69): Mage::run('gardenflowerpro...', 'website')
#17 {main}
```

**I have a MultiPHP Manager on the server and it lets me go down all the way to php55.**

Comment: read the error, table crashed, repair it...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to upgrade your store's Magento to latest 1.x or 2.x version, since your Magento version seems to have many security vulnerabilities.

When you upgrade Magento's version, it provides many enhancements like:

- Better security
- New features
- Compatibility with newer versions of PHP and Mysql

Please let me know if you have any specific reason to stick with such older version of Magento.

Comment: Thank you Mohit for your suggestion. The problem is  that I spent a lot of time putting everything together and EVERY time I tried to upgrade - it completely destroys everything = not ONLY the theme, but there is no way to migrate the products from 1.3 to something like 1.9. I had to do that by hand on another domain (that was a lot of work to punch in 1100 products into the new version of Magento and set everything up again).